# How to set column size dynamically in kendo ui listview grid

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently I have set column size 3 and row 7 by default and it displayed correctly in grid.
Like this:

```
var gridrow = 7;
var gridcolumn = 3;
var gridrowcolumn = gridrow * gridcolumn;
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
 data:[ ],
 pageSize: gridrowcolumn,
});
$("#listView").kendoListView({
 dataSource: dataSource,
 selectable: "multiple",
 editable: true,    
});
```

and set data in grid and initialize the view for 3 column grid like this.

```
var total = dataSource.data().length;
dataSource.insert(total, {categoryClass:"product", categoryTitle: "india", categoryId:"3" );
dataSource.insert(total, {categoryClass:"product", categoryTitle: "gujarat", categoryId:"2" );
dataSource.insert(total, {categoryClass:"product", categoryTitle: "surat", categoryId:"1" );
```

But I want to change columns programatically and add extra data.

Ex. if I change column to 4 then add one extra column like this and give condition to properly work.

```
if(gridcolumn == 4) {
dataSource.insert(total, {categoryClass:"product", categoryTitle: "asia", categoryId:"4" );
}
```

If I do this then completely work but this type of code, increase line of code and performance will become slow.

So is there any other solution to become grid column dynamically and performance is increased and will not use condition every time for column size.